# Placeholder alignment - Getting CallbackOnCollectedDelegate error

Tags: vb.net, delegates, callback, garbage-collection

In a windows form that I have created in VB.NET, for one of its text boxes, I am using a code that simulates a placeholder in the textbox, i.e, a text that is, by default, there in the text box, and when the user clicks on the text box, the text disappears to allow the user to write his text. And if the user hasn't written anything and clicks out of the text box, the text re-appears.

[image]

As you can see, the placeholder is aligned to the right. However, as per my code, when the user clicks on the text box (text box has got focus), the text to be entered should now be aligned to the left. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub TextBox_ProjectName_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox_ProjectName.GotFocus
    If TextBox_ProjectName.Text = "(required)" Then
        TextBox_ProjectName.Text = ""
    End If
    TextBox_ProjectName.ForeColor = Color.Black
    TextBox_ProjectName.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
    TextBox_ProjectName.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left
End Sub
```

And when the text box has lost focus (user clicks out of the text box), the placeholder re-appears if the user hasn't entered anything in the text box.

Code:

```
Private Sub TextBox_ProjectName_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox_ProjectName.LostFocus
    If TextBox_ProjectName.Text = "" Then
        TextBox_ProjectName.Text = "(required)"
        TextBox_ProjectName.ForeColor = Color.Gray
        TextBox_ProjectName.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic)
        TextBox_ProjectName.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I am having the following error on the `TextBox_ProjectName.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right` code. This is in Visual Basic 2008.

[image]

In Visual Basic 2010, I am having the CallbackOnCollectedDelegate error.

[image]

I believe that both versions are projecting the same error.

Can anyone help me on that? If so, please include information about what is a delegate, what is a callback, and what is the garbage collector.

### Code modified, problem removed but another crops up.

Now, in my subroutine handling the text box's GotFocus, I have tried putting the codes that are outside the `If` statement...inside, like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox_ProjectName_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox_ProjectName.GotFocus
    If TextBox_ProjectName.Text = "(required)" Then
        TextBox_ProjectName.Text = ""
        TextBox_ProjectName.ForeColor = Color.Black
        TextBox_ProjectName.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
        TextBox_ProjectName.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    End If
End Sub
```

The subroutine for handling the text box's LostFocus remains the same.

```
Private Sub TextBox_ProjectName_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox_ProjectName.LostFocus
    If TextBox_ProjectName.Text = "" Then
        TextBox_ProjectName.Text = "(required)"
        TextBox_ProjectName.ForeColor = Color.Gray
        TextBox_ProjectName.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic)
        TextBox_ProjectName.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem that I am having now is that on the text box getting focus, the text is not aligning to the left and is not getting the 'Regular' font style.

[image]

If, however, I comment the `TextBox_ProjectName.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right` code in the `LostFocus` subroutine, the text successfully aligns to the left and becomes 'Regular' styled, but then, on the text box losing focus and the user hasn't entered anything, the placeholder is now obviously aligned to the left, which makes it ugly given that previously it was aligned to the right.

[image]

[image]

[image]

What's the problem here? Why is the text not left-aligned when nothing is commented?

I know that I have posted a really long question here. Sorry. However, if only the first part of the question is addressed, I will be glad. The second part can be considered as a supplement.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.